# Can my companions take items out of legacy storage?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Can my companions take items like crafting materials out of my legacy storage to craft items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When crafting, all materials in the Legacy storage are available to you.

The are drawn in this order:

1. Materials in your inventory
2. Materials in your cargo hold
3. Materials in your Legacy storage

This allows you to maximize both accessibility of materials to your alts as well as reduce what you're carrying around.

Comment: Note: Legacy storage does not work for purchasing items for vendors though. I must have those in your inventory or cargo hold.

Comment: @Mufasa That's correct; tokens, Cartel Market ceritificates, prefabs, dark projects, scrap, and event/FP currencies are not drawn from Legacy Storage (nor the Cargo Hold).